# How can I figure out where I created my Bitcoin wallet?

Tags: e-wallet, lost-wallet

I deposited and played at freebitcoin.com and after playing I was able to withdraw my bitcoins. I saw the transaction at blockr but don't remember which website I created that Bitcoin address on. Please help.

Comment: This is not enough information for anyone to help you.  For instance, what kind of wallet do you use (web wallet, mobile wallet, desktop wallet)?  Nobody can tell you how to recover your bitcoin if we know nothing but the address you received it to.

Comment: I've removed the address as it won't help in the discovery.

Answer (score 4):

A bitcoin private key is a random 256 bit number. A bitcoin address is deterministically derived from that private key. Everyone uses the same procedure to do so. Therefore, it is impossible to figure out where you created the wallet based one a bitcoin address.

Your browser history, however, might lead you to the correct website. You can limit the websites to check to those you visited when you suspect to have created the wallet, therefore narrowing down the places to search.

Since you don't know the website and probably need credentials to access you wallet there, you probably saved the password in your browser. Since the number of saved passwords probably is much smaller than the number of websites you visited, **searching your saved passwords might be the best way to go.** Every modern browser should be able to show them to you, along with the website they belong to.

Comment: The stored password list is a good idea! You might want to highlight that in your answer.

Comment: @Murch Thx. Did so.